# Code size of Instruction set Architecture

Tags: computer-architecture

For the following assume that values A, B, C, D, E, and F reside in memory. Also assume that instruction operation codes are represented in 8 bits, memory addresses are 64 bits, and register addresses are 6 bits, and data values are 32-bit integers (4 bytes each).

Output

[image: output]

Here are some calculation results

[image: Calculations]

I don't understand Code size part, was not able to find it online too. Can someone explain how Code size part there is calculated? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, made-up computer architectures are not standardized by their nature. Only your professor can tell you how instructed are encoded in your specific made-up architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add up the number of bits per operation, register address, and memory address. I don't know why they mention data value, it doesn't really have any bearing on the calculation

---

In the stack code, there are three operations done on four memory addresses.

`Stack size = 8 * operations + 64 * addresses = 8*4 + 64*3 = 224`

In the accumulator code, there are three operations done on three memory addresses.

`Accumulator size = 8 * operations + 64 * addresses + = 8*3 + 64*3 = 216`

In the register-memory code, there are four register address accesses and three memory accesses

`Register-memory size = 8 * operations + 64 * addresses + 6 * registers = 8*3 + 64*3 + 6*4 = 240`

In the register-store code, there are six register address accesses and three memory accesses

`Register-store size = 8 * operations + 64 * addresses + 6 * registers = 8*4 + 64*3 + 6*6 = 260`